# phpMyAdmin Shows Deprecation errors

Tags: phpmyadmin

When I log in into my phpMyAdmin 4.5.4.1deb2ubuntu2 on my Ubuntu 16.04.3 server I get a lot of deprecation notices:

```
Deprecation Notice in ./../php/php-gettext/streams.php#48


Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; StringReader has a deprecated constructor

Backtrace

./../php/php-gettext/gettext.inc#41: require()
./libraries/select_lang.lib.php#477: require_once(./../php/php-gettext/gettext.inc)
./libraries/common.inc.php#569: require(./libraries/select_lang.lib.php)
./index.php#12: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)
```

Here is the [complete list of error messages](https://ghostbin.com/paste/penv2).

I tried to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42178241) here but this also did not work. 
Also `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` changed nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall the packages for phpmyadmin with `aptitude reinstall phpmyadmin php-gettext php-mbstring` or `apt install --reinstall phpmyadmin php-gettext php-mbstring` and reload your page.

If they are shown again it could be also E_USER_DEPRECATED, change your error reporting in php.ini as follows

> error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT

and reload your Webserver.

Comment: even adding this to `php.ini` I'm still getting same results.. many deprecation notices..