# Deprecation Notice in ./libraries/classes/Url.php#253 error

Tags: php, sql, url, settings, helper

I'm getting an error when i am trying to open Settings. It's popping up when i click on Setting.

```
Deprecation Notice in ./libraries/classes/Url.php#253
```

Is there anyone who have any idea that how i can solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would help if we knew what *settings* you are talking about and what code you are using.

Comment: Hi there, 
When i log in to **phpmyadmin**  and click on the **settings** to add my site's informations i get this *Deprecation Notice in ./libraries/classes/Url.php#253** error.

Comment: You can check out the solutions in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37002494/php-7-with-phpmyadmin-gives-lots-of-deprecation-notices